# Loading Google Maps API with wp_enqueue_script

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I'm trying to load the Google Maps API using the following syntax:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_google_maps');
```

...

```
function load_google_maps()
{
  // The actual API key is configured in an options page
  $key = get_option('google_maps_api_key');
  $gmaps_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' . $key . '&amp;sensor=false';
  wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', $gmaps_url, NULL, NULL);
}
```

WordPress is escaping the "&" to "&#038". This actually makes the Google server reject the request. When I type it directly into browser address bar with "&sensor=false" at the end, it loads fine.

I saw a bug of this kind mentioned in the WordPress trac system: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9243 but it was dismissed as invalid, and the admin responding to the request showed somehow that the "&#038" approach was fine. It is definitely not fine from Google's point of view.

I could of course just get the function to echo the HTML as a script tag, but I'd rather use the wp_enqueue_script system if possible.

Anyone know of a solution to this?

Cheers,

raff

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've got something similar in our code, and it's working fine (even encoded as `&#038`).  I suspect your problem is that it's being double-encoded, as you already have `&amp;`.  Trying changing it to:

```
$gmaps_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' . $key . '&sensor=false';
```

For what it's worth, our (working) code is:

```
wp_register_script('googlemaps', 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?' . $locale . '&key=' . GOOGLE_MAPS_V3_API_KEY . '&sensor=false', false, '3');
wp_enqueue_script('googlemaps');
```

(`$locale` in this case is set to `hl=en`)

**Edit**

Looks like the behaviour's changed in the latest version of WordPress - the above doesn't work (but I'll leave it for people on legacy versions).  The only alternative I can see to echoing the script is to add a `clean_url` filter, something like this:

```
add_filter('clean_url', 'so_handle_038', 99, 3);
function so_handle_038($url, $original_url, $_context) {
    if (strstr($url, "googleapis.com") !== false) {
        $url = str_replace("&#038;", "&", $url); // or $url = $original_url
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Pretty ugly, but perhaps marginally better than echoing the script, as it'll still use the WordPress dependency management.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response - I have been away. Thanks very much Hobo - yes, it was as simple as that. Replacing `&amp;` with `&` worked perfectly.

Comment: Calling Google Maps API, at least for version 3.X and higher, works correctly with &#038; in the URL.  Google is converting the hex code back into a simple & before parsing the parameters.    You can verify this by calling a Google Maps API V3 directly with the &#038; in place of & for parameter passing or by using Firefox + Firebug and viewing your script list.

Comment: As an aside, I've been working with Google Maps on WordPress for Store Locator Plus for 2+ years now.  I strongly recommend putting sensor=false as your first parameter.   Not doing so will cause issues with some themes because they break the URL filters and kill everything after the first '&'.   sensor=true|false is required, so put it first and you'll have far fewer theme/plugin conflicts.

Comment: Just add .'&sensor=false' in the end Works perfectly for me.