# WordPress: remove #038 from shortcode

Tags: wordpress, special-characters, shortcode

Simple example of a shortcode:

```
function s_print( $atts ){
    return 'http://abc.com/?foo=1&bar=2';
}
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 's_print' );
```

And it returns:

```
http://abc.com/?foo=1&#038;bar=2
```

This function inserts a link to page's body via shortcode `[my_shortcode]`, but `&` is always changed to `&#038`, and this breaks the link (it's not working anymore).
I googled a lot. There are some solutions:

```
wp_specialchars_decode($foo);
remove_filter('the_content','wptexturize');
```

But those seems to be only for use in theme (functions.php) and it doesn't work for a shortcode (I tried adding it before or inside the shortcode function).

I don't want to fall to last solution, which is commenting some lines in WordPress `formatting.php` file because I'm working on a plugin which will be used by many people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem that I addressed with the `clean_url` filter.  See the edit on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504142/loading-google-maps-api-with-wp-enqueue-script/9504653#9504653).

It wasn't in a shortcode, so I can't guarantee it'll work in your particular situation.  Might be worth a shot though.

**EDIT** by *oyatek*
(modified solution from the link aboove):

```
function so_handle_038($content) {
    $content = str_replace(array("&#038;","&amp;"), "&", $content); 
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'so_handle_038', 199, 1);
```

Comment: Solution described by the link didn't work for a shortcode, but I modified it a little bit and it worked! Thanks a million! I thought it's hopeless! Let me add a solution to your answer.

Comment: In my case it worked with `clean_url` instead `the_content`. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The fact is when you use the Visual Editor, the `&` will be changed to `&amp;`. But if you use the Text Editor, single `&` followed by no character remains the same while `&sth` will be changed to `&#038;sth`.

Altogether `&` will be changed to either `&amp;` or `&#038;`. I think the solution above:

```
function so_handle_038($content) {
    $content = str_replace(array("&#038;","&amp;"), "&", $content); 
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'so_handle_038', 199, 1);
```

is a sort of overkill, because `so_handle_038();` decodes all `&amp;`s and `&#038;`s in the `$content` while in your case, you need to decode only those in the `$atts` array. Your shortcode entry is probably like this:

```
[my_shortcode url="http://abc.com/?foo=1&bar=2" /]
```

and the `$atts` will be:

```
array( 'url' => "http://abc.com/?foo=1&amp;bar=2" )
```

or:

```
array( 'url' => "http://abc.com/?foo=1&#038;bar=2" )
```

so you only need to decode `$atts['url']`:

```
html_entities_decode($atts['url']);
```

before you try to do anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

This one was a bandaid hack which I used, basically to fix the issue in wordpress (As I had my link inside of an iFrame), I went to Bitly and created a link WITHOUT the ampersand & sign!  So finally I ended up getting a link that DIDN'T have any of the & signs but STILL pointed at the same location (Plus I got free tracking via Bit.ly for the link so DOUBLE bonus as I can check how many times the link was clicked).  Not the "Best" solution, but heck it worked for me and I didn't have to waste time trying to figure out some other solution for the & symbol in Wordpress.