# How to send Multiple parameters in URL of wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to send the multiple parameters in wordpress like

- hostname/wordpress/form/?amt=".$amount."&tp=".$trans_period

is the url am calling on click of 'anchor tag'.

but am getting the converted url in address bar as

- hostname/wordpress/form/?amt=7.99#038;tp=M

the '&' is replaced with '#038;' 
thats why am not able to get the second parameter 'tp'

Comment: What's the code you use for generating the URL + QueryString. It looks like you're url-encoding a bit to much.

Comment: am just calling this url onclick of anchor tag only...

Answer (score 1):

We hit something similar for the Google maps API.  Hooking in to the `clean_url` filter might help, though it's a bit ugly.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504142/loading-google-maps-api-with-wp-enqueue-script/9504653#9504653).