# Gmaps NoAPIKey error

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps

I'm loading two scripts into my checkout page:

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    if ( function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) ) {
        if ( is_woocommerce() && is_checkout() ) {
            wp_register_script('google-maps-api', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[iprovidemykeyhere]&callback=initMap');
            wp_register_script('location_tracker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/track_location.js', array('google-maps-api'));

            wp_enqueue_script('google-maps-api');
            wp_enqueue_script('location_tracker');

        }
    }
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts', 999 );
```

... but I get the following although I am correctly providing the key in the URL above:

> Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
>
> Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required

Comment: Any chance the URL is being double-encoded (can you paste the URL appearing in the generated HTML)?  If it is, my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9504653/1714) may help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1:** please go to your [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com) and enable `Google Maps JavaScript API` from overview tab, so go to `Credentials` tab and make an API key for your project.

**Step 2:** add below line to your html and change `yourKEYhere` by your api key.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourKEYhere"></script>
```

**Step 3:** use `gmaps.js` [plugin](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/).

Good luck!