# Enqueue script url: put variable in url

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created an option tab with Advanced Custom fields where you can paste your Google Maps API key, so I don't have to put the API key in the code over and over again when starting a new project.

Get the value of the custom field where I put my API key:

```
$mapsApi = get_field('maps_api', 'option');
```

Now, I am loading the API key with the following script:

```
function bredweb_files() {
  // scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('maps-api', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY', array(), '1', true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bredweb_files' );
```

(That is of course not the only thing I'm loading, also styles and other scripts)

So my question is, how do I place that variable (`$mapsApi`) in the url, instead of the `YOUR_API_KEY`?

I've tried the obvious: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=$mapsApi`, yet that doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried just putting the variable there `"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=$mapsApi`

Comment: @swadhwa yes I did.

Comment: It doesn't work like how, what error or warning do you get

Comment: The message I get: You are using this API without a key. So it's not getting the value of the custom field. So it's not adding the variable to the url.

Comment: Maybe also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504142/loading-google-maps-api-with-wp-enqueue-script

Comment: shouldn't second param to `get_field` be a post_id? what is 'option' that you passed to `get_field`

Comment: No, it has to be 'option' otherwise it won't detect it as such.

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: you must be adding 'pasting' this api key on a certain post right?

Comment: @swadhwa how do you mean pasting?

Comment: on what page do you put this key and save?

Comment: My first line: (; "I've created an option tab with Advanced Custom fields where you can paste your Google Maps API key"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do such type of things.

```
function bredweb_files() {
          $mapsApi = get_field('maps_api', 'option');

          wp_enqueue_script('maps-api', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? key='.$mapsApi, array(), '1', true);}
          add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bredweb_files' );
```

Comment: @swadhwa Then i am sure he is not properly getting value from db. Otherwise above function is absolutely correct.

Comment: it's still not correct, you can't use a variable defined outside the scope of a function. maybe add this: `global $mapsApi`

Comment: oh according to your sense its right, but i am assuming like this:function bredweb_files() {$mapsApi = get_field('maps_api', 'option');
          wp_enqueue_script('maps-api', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? key='.$mapsApi, array(), '1', true);}
          add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bredweb_files' );}

Comment: Yes it is like that, yet it still doesn't get the value of the custom field when adding the variable to the url.

Comment: I've tried your solution again. I only forgot to remove the "}" at the end of the line, so it wound't close the function prematurely. Thank you!